# An experiment consists of rolling a fair die 100 times.

Tags: sampling

If this experiment is repeated, what is the sampling distribution of the proportion of the 100 tosses that land with one spot in the top face?

the P(getting a 1) = 1/6

how do I find the proportion value if idk how many times of getting a 1? do I understand this question correctly?

Comment: The proportion is the actual number of $1$s received divided by $100$.  You are asked to assess the probability of each proportion.  The ones that will be highest will be $0.16$ and $0.17$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a binomial

$$P(X=x/100)=\binom{100}{x}\Big(\frac{1}{6}\Big)^{x}\Big(\frac{5}{6}\Big)^{100-x}$$

$x=0,1,2...,100$